# IndexError in Decreasing lists in python

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python, i keep getting this error. I need to know whats wrong with the code, it doesnt execute when passed a decreasing list using range() :
IndexError:List index out of range

```
def is_monotone(heights):

    j = 0
    if len(heights) == 0:
        return True
    for i in heights:
        if heights[j + 1] >= heights[j]:
            j += 1

            return True


        return False
```

Comment: What is that supposed to be doing?

Comment: Are you sure the return False, is within the for loop?

Comment: Can you specify the scenario where the error turns up. I tried running your code and it worked.

Comment: Please show how the function is called, i.e. the "decreasing list".

Comment: What is that function supposed to do? Monotone what? Increasing or decreasing? It seems not to do any of those.

Comment: the function is called (not is_monotone(range(5, 0, -1) cdarke, khelwood- to check whether for any x all successors are greater or equal to x. if equal or greater, or it is an empty it returns true else it returns False if it is a decreasing list or the successor(s) is/are less than x

Comment: More than an index error, your algorithm won’t work like this. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from:

```
for i in heights:
    if heights[j + 1] >= heights[j]:
        j += 1
```

As you iterate through `height`, at some time `j + 1 = len(height)`, and then `heights[j + 1]` is out of range.

You should loop like this:

```
for i in range(len(heights) - 1):
    if heights[j + 1] >= heights[j]:
        j += 1
```

As tobias pointed it out, there is no more need of `j`, you can use `i` instead.

```
for i in range(len(heights) - 1):
    if heights[i + 1] >= heights[i]:
        return True
```

Comment: Since `i` now is the index, there is no need for `j` anymore.

Comment: Not sure whether that `return True` is correct, either... but that's for OP to decide.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through the whole list adding `1` to `j` every time. If you have a list of n items then the highest index will be n-1. So when you have reached the last item in heights, then `j` is n-1 but you are checking if `height[j+1] >= heights[j]` which will try to find the index n which is out of range, because that index does not exist. You might want to add a check to see if `j+1 > len(heights)`

```
def is_monotone(heights):

    j = 0
    if len(heights) == 0:
        return True
    for i in heights:
        if j + 1 > len(heights):
            return True
        if heights[j + 1] >= heights[j]:
            j += 1

            return True


        return False
```

Note also that for any list that is bigger than two items where `heights[1] > heights[0]` will return True because of where you've placed your return statement.

Answer (score 1):

When you reach the end of the list, (when you have `j = len(heights)-1`), the index `j+1 = len(list)` is out of range, thus raising the `IndexError` exception.

However, even with correct indexing, **your function won’t tell you if your list is monotone!** It will rather return you the True value if element 1 is greater than element 0…

There is a proposition of working function:

```
def is_monotone(heights):
    if len(heights) == 0:
        return True
    steps = []
    for j in range(len(heights)-1):
        steps.append(heights[j+1]-heights[j])
    if all(step >= 0 for step in steps) or all(step <= 0 for step in steps):
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `return False` is outside the for loop , otherwise you would only be getting an error when you send a list with 1 element.

The issue is that when you send a decreasing list (or a list with 1 element) , you are iterating till `j` becomes the index of the last element (that is `len(heights) - 1)` , hence when you try to access `heights[j + 1]` , it errors out with the `IndexError:List index out of range` error.

You should only iterate from `0` to `len(heights) - 2` , you can use a range function for that (In range you should give `len(heights) -1` since range does not include the last element when i.

Example -

```
def is_monotone(heights):

    if len(heights) == 0:
        return True
    for j in range(len(heights)-1):
        if heights[j + 1] >= heights[j]:
            return True
    return False
```

---

But then again, if what your function is checking is whether the list is monotonically increasing (all the elements are increasing), your logic is a bit off, you should not return True when you find a single instance of next element being larger than the first.

Instead you should return false when you find an instance of decreasing numbers at continous indexes and return True outside the for loop. Please note this is only if your function is to check if the numbers are in an increasing sequence.

Example -

```
def is_monotone(heights):

    if len(heights) == 0:
        return True
    for j in range(len(heights)-1):
        if heights[j + 1] < heights[j]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: thanks anand, it checks for an increasing sequence. So this works for me